# Making a Attribute-ordered networks with igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am following this tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/hobsonresearch/r-resources/attribute-ordered-networks
and I have data that is very similar to the data used in the tutorial.

I am trying to make a attribute-ordered network with my data, using the same code in the tutorial. However, the way the lay-out is set up, doesn't work for me.

This is de code that is used to set up the lay-out:

`x <- V(atnet)$x`

`y <- V(atnet)$rank`

`attord<- cbind(x, y)`

Edit: This is what `attord` looks like

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

The `attord<- cbind(x, y)` is used for the lay-out in the following code:

```
plot.igraph(atnet,
        layout=attord, #sets as attribute-ordered layout, defined above
        vertex.size=nodesize1, #this references the node circle size, set above
        vertex.label.family="sans", #uses sans font style
        vertex.label.color = "black", #sets node label colors (ids) to black
        vertex.label.cex=labelsize, #this references the node label size, set above
        vertex.color="white", #sets node fill color to white
        edge.width=tiewidth1, #this references the edge width, set above
        edge.arrow.size=0.01, #this makes the arrows on the ends of the edges very small
        edge.curved=TRUE, #this makes the edges curved
        edge.loop.angle=1,
        edge.color=E(atnet)$color)
```

When I use this code I get the error: Error in v - vr[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

I found out that I get this error because the `layout = attord` does not work, when I use `layout_nicely()` I do get a graph, but not in de lay-out that I need. [This is the graph that I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIhJJ.png). Now my question is: is there a mistake in this code? And how can I make the graph with this code?

Comment: `attord` should be able to be converted into a numeric matrix with two columns. Try `str(attord)` to check this.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1, build a random example.

```
require(igraph)
set.seed(n)
n              <- 10
atnet          <- sample_gnp(n, 0.6, directed=TRUE)
V(atnet)$name  <- letters[1:n]
V(atnet)$rank  <- n - seq_len(n)
E(atnet)$color <- rainbow(length(degree(atnet, tail_of(atnet, E(atnet)))))
nodesize1      <- round(runif(n, 10, 24))
labelsize      <- NULL
tiewidth1      <- 4*runif(ecount(atnet))
```

Step 2, build a two column layout matrix.

```
## build layout matrix, point = (0, y).
## hive layout with one axis x=0.
x <- rep(0, vcount(atnet))
y <- V(atnet)$rank
attord <- cbind(x, y)
class(attord)
```

Step3, plot.

```
## >help(plot.igraph)
plot.igraph(
  atnet,
  layout              = attord,    # sets as attribute-ordered layout, defined above.
  vertex.size         = nodesize1, # this references the node circle size, set above.
  vertex.label.family = "sans",    # uses sans font style.
  vertex.label.color  = "black",   # sets node label colors (ids) to black.
  vertex.label.cex    = labelsize, # this references the node label. size, set above
  vertex.color        = "white",   # sets node fill color to white.
  edge.width          = tiewidth1, # this references the edge width, set above.
  edge.arrow.size     = 0.01,      # this makes the arrows on the ends of the edges very small.
  edge.curved         = TRUE,      # this makes the edges curved.
  edge.loop.angle     = 1,
  edge.color          = E(atnet)$color
)
```